# In facebook purchase net banking option not working

Tags: facebook, in-app-purchase

When i try to purchase chips in facebook game(https://apps.facebook.com/mindimultiplayer/)  i show error prompt.how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming question. For end user support in regard to that particular ap, please contact the app developer instead.

Comment: This is not an issue actually my firewall blocking connection.